# Process Incoming Mail with External Script with Exim

Tags: exim

I have an Exim mail server, it is configured so that each incoming email has its content handled by a PHP file.

With the help of a third-party library, my PHP file can extract the subject, sender, recipient, attachments, etc.

It happens that there will be a change in my infrastructure and this script will no longer be able to stay on the same server as EXIM, as it involves a database now on another network, etc.

Is there any way to configure Exim to send email content to an external URL instead of a PHP file?

I even considered keeping my PHP script running and taking all the data stream I received from EXIM and manually cURLing it all to the new server, but I'm afraid that Apache's request limits will be slammed along the way.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite unlikely that you want to do that. If exim can send the mails to your script, what's to stop another script also sending junkmail there? If you don't know the answer then don't set this up. Instead you should maybe set up a separate mail server where your script has to run and have mail forwarded to that.

Having said that, the direction you are going isn't crazy if you know what you are doing.  You don't want to use curl, but you could write a custom script running in the old server and use that to contact the script running on the new server. You need to

- make sure that you have security in place so that only your scripts can connect
- make sure that you have error handling in place - what happens if the remote server disappears for a time? Should your script retry?
- make sure you have a bunch of monitoring and tests in place so you know when something breaks and what needs to be fixed

That's probably quite a complicated programming job to do. It might be easier to get the access you need to the database you need available where your script has to run.